# How to get around Malus Darkblade unit replenishment penalty?

Tags: warhammer-ii-total-war

The [Malus Darkblade](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0sPbjHEnSDE) of Dark Elves in Total War Warhammer II has a unique mechanic: every round he gets "possession points" - 2 if he is in the field, 1 if he is in a city. When he hits 10 points (or maybe even 9?) his armies stop regenerating after combat, even when they are in an owned city. Of course, he can drink an elixir that gives -10 points, but it's expensive and the price keeps rising after each purchase. This leads to the situation where I have to keep sacking cities just to afford the "fix", which greatly cripples my progress.

I've tried to give the wounded units to another general, but it seems that the penalty is global. I've heard, that you can, in theory, go around it by recruiting lots of Death Hags, which give regeneration bonus - is that true?

Following this [reddit thread about replenishment](https://www.reddit.com/r/totalwar/comments/6lprv9/psa_replenishment_how_does_it_work/) it seems possible in theory:

- being in owned (or allied) region lets you replenish casualties in your army by 8% per turn. It's 8% of a single unit HP (240 HP per turn for a unit with 3000 max HP), and to simplify for units with multiple troops (in case there are 90 troops in unit) it's 0.08x90 = 7 replenished troops per turn.
- This gets updated by + 12% in a city
- Death Hag gives max +20 % (8% +12% from 3 upgrades)
- 10 points possession gives -50%
- Supernatural Tissue skill – +30% replenishment rate (lord’s army) - I think, this affects only Malus tho

So fully possessed, in a city with ST skill I should be at 0 (8+12+30-50) and each Hag should push me to a positive value - unless there are some hidden rules that I've missed?

Comment: I haven't played Malus enough to fully figure him out, but based on my current understanding: You should not be always chucking potion to keep the possession off. It is more of a tactical option, when you are building economy and being defensive, control the possession to gain loyalty and the construction bonus, then let the possession kick in as you expand and let the bonus combat stats help you win battles. Though I remember in the Vortex campaign there is something you can do to reduce the price of the elixir, I'll check that out and give an answer later

Comment: @BenOng In the "Mortal Empires" you can get elixir for free when you'll conquer 10 provinces... which is not easy with him starting near skaven-infested area

Comment: I just came across an interesting suggestion you can consider too: Merge units, just merge your troops and recruit new ones. with the penalty it might just be faster to recruit new troops than replenishing them.

Comment: @BenOng I thought about it, but unless you stick to the basic units, it will be quite pricey. Also you loose unit experience

Comment: won't deny, but 2 hight rank but injured units probably won't do as well as 1 high rank and 1 low rank but with full strength, that's why the merging system was in place no? I also suspect that idea was for the initial phase where the bulk of your army is still Dread Spears

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR**

Most reliable method to negate Malus's penalty: Get both Lord's and Death Hag's replenishment boost, garrison in town. Done.

---

It is certainly possible to overcome the replenishment penalty of Malus's possession. Replenishment rate is affected by a lot of factors and you can easily find ways to boost it.

For this question I'll have a list of **possible replenishment boost available to Hag Greaf(Malus's faction):**

1. Death Hag - up to 20%
2. Garrison - 20% (Climate might reduce this)
3. Black Ark - 10% (Near sea only)
4. Sacrifice to Kain? - 20%
5. Growth build chain - up to 4%
6. Pasture build chain - up to 8% (certain provinces only)
7. Medicinal plant build chain - up to 12% (certain provinces only)
8. Lord's skill - Malus up to 45%, others up to 15% (All Dark Elves lord have Elven Healing which gives 15% replenishment at rank 3)
9. Items - ?% (This one will take some time to calculate but on the bright side, if you obtain any equipment that boost replenishment, you can pass it from one lord to another depending on whose army needs it more.)
10. Events - ?% (This will probably remain ? unless I can find all possible events and their effects but since it is almost random I wouldn't count on it to offset global penalties.)

I'll expand this list as I find more.

From the numbers I've gathered so far you can see that **Malus himself will have no problem offsetting the penalty, other lords can <s>almost</s> do it just by having a Death Hag, the right skills and garrisoned in a town**.

If you need significant replenishment, bringing a Black Ark nearby and perform the ritual Sacrifice to Kain will provide a 30% boost. Just take note that replenishment bonus from Black Ark and Death Hag only applies once, having one of each is enough.

But to also answer your secondary concerns of factors you missed, here are some common Negative replenishment rate factors:

1. Climate: when you try to expand into unsuitable climate you may have up to 15% penalty, offsetting the Lord's Elven healing skill.
2. Post Battle option: Releasing(Ransom I think is the word used for Dark Elves) captives from battles will result in temporary lower replenishment rate by about 10%
3. Events: This is most unpredictable, but you can always check the global effects on the top bar to see if any recent events is giving you replenishment penalty.
4. Hostile Heroes activity: Some heroes can cause your army to have lesser replenishment for a certain duration, this can be as high as 40% penalty.

On the side note, I wouldn't suggest letting Malus be permanently possessed, on top of the replenishment penalty there is also Loyalty penalty which is in my opinion, more problematic and harder to overcome. Fortunately you can take 2 elixir at once to cause a reverse chance to gain loyalty instead to counter it, but I wouldn't suggest pushing that limit since a single mistake might mean an entire army abandoning you.

Comment: I'm afraid that it doesn't work: I have level 23 Malus with 3 Death Hags giving +60% healing inside a settlement which should give 60+20-50 = 30% healing and only the legendary lord has any healing on him.

Comment: If I am not wrong, the replenishment rate from Death Hag does not stack, you'll only benefit from the highest which by your information about 20%, therefore the actual value is 20+20-50 = -10%, Malus himself is probably benefiting from some replenishment that does not also affects the troops. I'll be playing my Malus campaign further later and will update more findings tomorrow.

Comment: Oh, and @Yasskier, the "recruit a lot of Death Hag" theory probably meant attaching one to each army and not all to Malus :)

Comment: Of course, I've attached all 3 hags to his army